# Vue v-bind class on event

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to put a class in vue if a certain element is present in an array. i am trying this way

```
          <span
          class="wishlist"
          @click="addToWishList(product.id)"
          v-bind:class="{selected : app.user.wishlists.includes(product.id)}">
          <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
        </span>
```

but it does not work . How could I do this in vue?

Comment: Seems to work fine https://jsfiddle.net/6csyb051/

Comment: did check `app.user.wishlists.includes(product.id)` returns a boolean value ?

Comment: show addToWishList method

Comment: what is this `product` variable? where is that coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this logic if you have only single selected item

```
<span class="wishlist" @click="addToWishList(product.id)"
         :class="{selected : selectedProductId===product.id}">
    <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
</span>

// your data
data:()=>{
  return {
    selectedProductId:null
  }
}

//method
addToWishList:function(id){
  this.selectedProductId = id;
  // rest of your logic
  ...
}
```

If you have multiple select

```
<span class="wishlist" @click="addToWishList(product.id)"
         :class="{selected : selectedProductIds.indexOf(product.id)>-1}">
    <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
</span>

// your data
data:()=>{
  return {
    selectedProductIds : null
  }
}

//method
addToWishList:function(id){
  let index = this.selectedProductIds.indexOf(id);
  // remove if already added
  if(index>-1){
    this.selectedProductIds.splice(index,1);
  }else{
    this.selectedProductIds.push(id);
  }

  // rest of your logic
  ...
}
```